# How can I change my current API to restful API?

Tags: web-services, rest, migration

I have something like this....
Books:
I have a php programme, that only accept post request only..., the link is something like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/books.php
```

If the user wanna to make request, they need do something like this:
Create:
params:

```
a=c             //a = action
d=a array of dataJson    //d = a defined books data in Json format
u=user id
s=session key
```

and I will return:

> ```
> 0 / !0     //0 = success case, !0 will give the error code
> ```
>
> array of id //the new create items
>   array id

Read:
params:

```
a=r                //a = action
id=the books id      (optional) //read the books from book id
title= a books title (optional) //read the books from title
author= an author    (optional) //read the books from author
u=user id
s=session key
```

//if no optional params, return all books.

and I will return:

> ```
> 0 / !0     //0 = success case, !0 will give the error code
> arrayOfBooks //books in array in Json format
> ```

Update:
params:

```
a=u                //a = action
id=the books id       //update the books from book id
d=a dataJson    //d = a defined books data in Json format
u=user id
s=session key
```

and I will return:

> ```
> 0 / !0     //0 = success case, !0 will give the error code
> ```

Delete:
params:

```
a=d                //a = action
id=the books id       //delete the books from book id
u=user id
s=session key
```

and I will return:

> ```
> 0 / !0     //0 = success case, !0 will give the error code
> ```

Is this ok for my current design to move to the "REST" way? Thank you.

Comment: do you have the interface under your control? supporting POST only is a big constraint for a restful api. you would drop the important 'uniform interface' principle. if you have the api under your control I would invest effort so you also support the other HTTP methods (PUT,DELETE, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use standard Http Status codes instead of your error codes.
You should use every single valuable parameter in the url in hierarchical order like this :

**Create should be:**

```
POST : http://www.mydomain.com/user/<userId>/books/create 
Http request body = your json data

Answer should be : 201 -> Created or 409 -> Conflict if there is one defined with the same title
```

If you use sessionId as an url parameter, you should use it in the url too.
You can use Http response body to pass bookIds back in a json array.

**Read should be:**

```
GET http://www.mydomain.com/user/<userId>/books/<bookId|@all>/<title|@all>/<author|@all>
```

**Update:**

```
POST http://www.mydomain.com/user/<userId>/books/<bookId> 
Http request body = your json data. (updatable fields only)

Answer : use HttpStatusCodes as response statuses and data as bookId
```

**Delete:**

```
POST http://www.mydomain.com/user/<userId>/books/<bookId>/delete

Answer : use HttpStatusCodes
```

Comment: umum, I have something to ask..... typically my books.php is in my /htdocs/, so that I can do my request, if I change to this way, what will inside in my /htdocs/path? How to let the php programme can read the path like...http://www.mydomain.com/user/1234/books/ ?? do I need to create a separate folder "user" in my /htdocs? and do I need to, add a new id, for example "1234", inside my user folders when a new user is assigned?

Comment: This has the problem of encoding the verb in the URL and overloading POST. I would recommend using PUT and DELETE in those instances instead.

Comment: I can not answer the php implementation of the problem.

Comment: Maybe some php framworks support dynamic url mapping. Of course the methods PUT and DELETE are the part of the restful implementation, but these methods are not always available.